# How do I install strongloop for node.js without errors?

Tags: node.js, installation, strongloop

I have a new Ubuntu system and I'm trying to install **strongloop**, but I'm seeing this error.

```
npm ERR! path /home/russ/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/nodefly-register/node_modules/request/node_modules/aws-sign
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/russ/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/nodefly-register/node_modules/request/node_modules/aws-sign' -> '/home/russ/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.4/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/nodefly-register/node_modules/request/node_modules/.aws-sign.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/russ/.npm/_logs/2018-09-10T14_04_24_761Z-debug.log
```

This leaves me hanging wondering what I should do different to get a successful install.

Russ

Comment: Please check if not : `https://github.com/strongloop/strongloop/issues/296`